# Disable multiple desktops on my Mac

Tags: mojave, mission-control

One desktop is plenty for me. In particular, I do not like the fact that when I drag a window to a side, it automatically switches to a new desktop. I don't want that.

I've unchecked all kinds of things related to multiple desktops, but none of it has managed to disable this feature.[image: 1]]

Comment: What do you see when you enter Mission Control (F3)? You must have at least a second desktop space, otherwise dragging a window to the side wouldn't do anything because there would be no additional space to drag it to.

Comment: Based on @daGUY's comment, go to mission control and delete all but 1 desktop.